# Get raw AngularJS "innerHTML" as it appears in the editor?

Tags: angularjs, escaping

I am working on some sort of documentation website and I want to have an Angular component side by side with its code, as it is shown in the editor. So it's ready to be copy pasted.

I tried to get the element's innerHTML but what I get is not the raw code. Is that possible? I want to avoid having to duplicate my code (once to display it, and the second time to show it in a `<xmp>` tag for another developer to copy-paste).

So basically I'm looking for a solution that always reflects the certain element's raw code as it appears in the editor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Am I right in thinking that by "not the raw code", you mean when you get the innerHTML you also get all the html tags from some sort of code formatting engine? And your question is whether it's possible to not have those HTML tags and just plain text?

Comment: Partially. I want to get the code just as I see it in my editor. So interpolations for example, will appear like this: `{{ example }}` and not as the variable's value. Just a reusable piece of code. Not sure if that's possible but worth a try!

Answer (score 1):

My colleague helped me solve this with a nice directive.

http://codepen.io/rogierpennink/pen/dNpwPa?editors=1111

```
.directive('htmlExtract', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      htmlExtractTarget: '='
    },
    link: {
      'pre': function(scope, element) {
        document.getElementById(scope.htmlExtractTarget).innerText = element[0].innerHTML;      
    }
    }
  };

});
```